# I am getting exception while creating new account in Dynamics 365 CRM via Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am creating new account using this code:

```
string cs = "connection";

ServiceClient serviceClient = new(cs);

Entity account = new("account");
account.Attributes.Add("name", "name");
account.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
account["custom_attribute1"] = "custom_attribute1";
account.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("custom_attribute2", custom_attribute2.Admin));

// serviceClient.Update(account);
serviceClient.Create(account);
```

I am refactoring old solution and there we had some custom attributes where value is Enum value. For some reason when I add it like this it's not working. I tried to use integer and string values but nothing changed.

I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ServiceClient.Create(Entity entity)

Exception message is by far not clear as I wanted it to be so I am struggling with debugging. I'd appreciate it if somebody can assist me

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check if the connection works correctly, normally you do a WhoAmIRequest after you initialize the ServiceClient

```
WhoAmIResponse response = serviceClient.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
```

if this piece doesn't throw an exception the connection works.

In order to create an account the simplest code is:

```
Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "TEST";
serviceClient.Create(account);
```

if you have problems to update a specific attribute, you need to check the attribute type, if for example is an OptionSet/Choice (you mentioned Enum that holding a numeric value can be connected) the syntax would be (assuming the value you want to put is 2):

```
account["custom_attribute1"] = new OptionSetValue(2);
```

Comment: OptionSetValue worked, amazing

Comment: by any chance do you know any good resource to get to know how to work with dynamics 365 in .net 6/7?

Comment: @ShahinJabbarov the Dynamics 365 c# code you see around works the exactly same way with the Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client, the main difference is the service client object, in the previous library is CrmServiceClient, in the new is ServiceClient (as your code)

Comment: I thought it's the new way to work with CRM instead of using Xrm.Sdk. That's surprising

Comment: the new library is compatible with the newer versions of .NET but they kept the syntax as the previous sdk to reduce the work when moving from the old library